# Celery Dump Memory into variable

Tags: python, celery

Im using Python Celery , and using memdump() I get the dump printed. However I was trying to dump the memory into a variable for printing later for instance, or even in logging. Is that possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: which `memdump` function are you referring to?  I'm not familiar with one in python natively.

Comment: the celery.debug.memdumb() function

It can use a file as parameter but i couldnt figure out how to make it a simple string return...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you take a look at [the source for `celery.utils.debug.memdump`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/utils/debug.html#memdump), it takes a `file` parameter.  This `file` parameter is pretty much any data type that can be passed as the `file` parameter to `print`, including our handy friend `io.StringIO`:

```
from celery.utils.debug import memdump
from io import StringIO
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

buffer = StringIO()
memdump(file=buffer)
log.info('memory dump: %s', buffer.getvalue())
```